# Converting Wind Movement to Wind Speed

Tags: meteorology, wind

I'm looking through historical weather station information from NOAA, and I notice some stations do not have wind speed information but do track Wind Movement(WDMV) over a 24 hour period in kilometers. Would a rough conversion of this to wind speed be: `Wind Movement/24 = Wind Speed(km/hr)`, this seems like too basic of a conversion and I realize is not a true average hourly wind speed.

Answer (score 1):

*IF* there has been a steady wind direction over that 24 hrs, then yes, this will give you the average wind speed.

If the wind has changed direction, then there may have been higher speeds that have partially cancelled each other out.